# TVS_EX_FADEINOUTEXPANDOS has no effect in a tree view

Tags: winapi, comctl32

The `TVS_EX_FADEINOUTEXPANDOS` extended style does not seem to have any effect on my tree view.

The documentation says:

> Fade expando buttons in or out when the mouse moves away or into a state of hovering over the control.

I set the style like this:

```
SetWindowTheme(hTreeCtrl, L"Explorer", NULL) ;
TreeView_SetExtendedStyle(hTreeCtrl,
                           TVS_EX_FADEINOUTEXPANDOS, TVS_EX_FADEINOUTEXPANDOS);
```

I'm on Windows 10 and the application is manifested to use visual styles.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: how you check that not work ? i just test it self tool - *when the mouse moves away or into a state of hovering over the control.* - no any effect. but when i **click** on another control (element in list view) - really fado (and the picture is very ugly twitches several times) - https://i.imgur.com/0rm9VR5.png

Comment: i be not use *TVS_EX_FADEINOUTEXPANDOS* at all

Comment: How I checked that it does not work: I can set `TVS_EX_FADEINOUTEXPANDOS` or not, I don't see any difference, nothing is fading in our out.

Comment: i also at first not don't see any difference, nothing is fading. only when i click on another control view effect (and very not nice)

Comment: @RbMm OK, I got it, the fading only happens if the the tree view doesn't have the focus. I won't use this mode, as it is rather pointless. Thanks.